# Fixed In-line Indentation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, thesis

I want to align content that starts in the middle of a line and content that starts at the beginning of the next line (for a thesis Authorization to Submit page). E.g.:

```
Major Professor:        ___________________________ Date: _________________
                        Professor Name, Ph.D.
```

An example I saw combined `\indent` and non-breaking spaces (backslash space). This is a little messy and difficult to get just right, since \indent adds a fixed space instead of jumping to an indent level (like MS Word).

Is there any way to jump to a fixed indent level (say, 2 inches into the body) in the middle of a line? Or is there a better way to do this?

This code illustrates the kind of thing I'm doing:

```
\noindent{}M\indent{}A\\
\indent{}B % does not line up!
```

I want something like:

```
\noindent{}M\fixindent{1in}A\\
\fixindent{1in}B % lines up!
```

Comment: You can use a `tabular`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `tabular`

```
 \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.35\textwidth}@{}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.075\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}@{}}
    Major Professor: &                        & Date: &     \\\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}
  \rule{0pt}{3ex}                   & Professor name, Ph.D.  &       &
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I needed to add another `@{}` at the beginning of the table spec to make it flush with other text on the page. Much better than indents and spaces!

Comment: @dafrazzman Glad it helped :)

Comment: You can also add `\noalign{\smallskip}` at the end of each underline row to separate the name from the blank line a little more. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Space_between_columns

Comment: @dafrazzman You can also add an invisible rule `\rule{0pt}{3ex}` in the first column of second row.